# Stacked Histograms of Grouped Data In pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

Say that I have a dataframe (df)with lots of values, including two columns, X and Y. I want to create a stacked histogram where each bin is a categorical value in X (say A and B), and inside each bin are stacks by values in Y (say a,b,c,...).

I can run df.groupby(["X","Y"]).size() to get output like below, but how can I make the stacked histogram from this?

```
A      a      14
       b      41
       c       4
       d       2
       e       2
       f      15
       g       1
       h       3
B      a      18
       b     37
       c       1
       d       3
       e       1
       f      17
       g       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I figured this out. First one needs to stack the data using; .unstack(level=-1)

This will turn it into an n by m array-like structure where n is number of X entries and m is the number of Y entries. From this form you can follow the outline given here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

So in total the command will be:

```
df.groupby(["X","Y"]).size().unstack(level=-1).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Kinda unwieldy looking though!